# Using HTML in Crispy Forms formset

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following FormHelper that I'm using to render a formset in Django Crispy Forms.  My understanding of the documentation indicates that I should end up with a formset with two HTML fields (name, user name) and two input fields, but this doesn't seem to be the case.  In fact, I only have the two form fields.

I'm unclear as to how I would go about adding HTML to a formset, given that the code below doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
class ProposalFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProposalFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.layout = Layout(
            HTML('{{ form.instance.proposal.name }}'),
            HTML('{{ form.instance.user.get_full_name }}'),
            Field('accepted', css_class='input-mini'),
            Field('rating', css_class='input-mini')
        )
        self.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Update'))
```

I should note that I've also tried to, alternatively, keep the FormHelper in the form itself and attach it to the {% crispy %} tag by doing: {% crispy formset formset.form.helper %}, but this had pretty much the same affect.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the lead developer of crispy-forms

The problem here is that you are using `bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html` which currently doesn't support specifying a layout.

It's stated clearly in the docs: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#custom-templates-and-table-inline-formsets

> This template doesn’t currently take into account any layout you have specified and only works with bootstrap template pack.

I'm aware this is not the expected behavior and there is an open issue about it. I'm hopefully working this week on solving it somehow.

Comment: Thanks.  I realised that after I posted this question and ended up using that template as an inspiration to write my own template.  Unfortunately, that means I'm writing pretty much everything in HTML rather than leveraging FormHelper, but I can live with that.